# Getting python dictionary item that has min value in a namedtupple

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, I have a dictionary of namedtuples and I want to get the dictionary item that has the tuple with smallest (min) value for a given attribute.

For example, given:

```
Named = collections.namedtuple('Named', ['A', 'B'])
named = {'id1': Named(9, 5), 'id2': Named(5, 4), 'id3': Named(7, 3)}
```

I might want to get the minimum of B, which would be

```
'id3': Named(7, 3)
```

If this was a list, I would do

```
min(named, key=operator.attrgetter('B'))
```

But, I'm having difficulty getting something similar to work with a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> min(named.values(), key=lambda x: x.B)
Named(A=7, B=3)
```

Or

```
>>> import operator
>>> min(named.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('B'))
Named(A=7, B=3)
```

Comment: Should do `key=lambda x: x.B` as it's more explicit

Comment: @user3483203. Thanks.. Updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

Use `named.values()`:

```
import collections
import operator

Named = collections.namedtuple('Named', ['A', 'B'])
named = {'id1': Named(9, 5), 'id2': Named(5, 4), 'id3': Named(7, 3)}

print(min(named.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('B')))
```

Prints:

```
Named(A=7, B=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Values are not distinct. You can have more then one value with a minimal `B`. To get all of them, you would have to get the minimal value of B and then fetch all keys that have such a `B`-value:

```
import collections

def getKeyWithMinBValue(d):
    """Yields the keys of dictionary entries that have minimum value of B"""
    m = min(d.values(),key=lambda x:x.B)
    for k in d:
        if d[k].B == m.B:
            yield k

Named = collections.namedtuple('Named', ['A', 'B'])
named = {'id1': Named(9, 5), 'id2': Named(5, 4), 'id3': Named(7, 3), 'id4':Named(99,3)}

# get all keys that have minimal value of B 
keys = getKeyWithMinBValue(named)

for k in keys:           # inefficient, creates throwaway dicts for printing.
    print( {k:named[k]}) # You could style the print other wise.
```

Output:

```
{'id3': Named(A=7, B=3)}
{'id4': Named(A=99, B=3)}
```